# React - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I wanted to use **"React Bootstrap Hamburger Menu"** [HamburgerMenu](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/navigation/hamburger-menu/#:%7E:text=Bootstrap%20Hamburger%20menu%20is%20a,by%20default%20for%20UX%20purpose.) copied the code from there and I get an error [errorScreen](https://ibb.co/2dppCsT)
"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. "Here is my code

**Mobile_Navbar.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  MDBNavbar,
  MDBNavbarBrand,
  MDBNavbarNav,
  MDBNavItem,
  MDBNavLink,
  MDBNavbarToggler,
  MDBCollapse,
  MDBContainer
} from 'mdbreact';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    collapseID: ''
  };

  toggleCollapse = collapseID => () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      collapseID: prevState.collapseID !== collapseID ? collapseID : ''
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <MDBContainer>
          <MDBNavbar
            color='light-blue lighten-4'
            style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
            light
          >
            <MDBContainer>
              <MDBNavbarBrand>Navbar</MDBNavbarBrand>
              <MDBNavbarToggler
                onClick={this.toggleCollapse('navbarCollapse1')}
              />
              <MDBCollapse
                id='navbarCollapse1'
                isOpen={this.state.collapseID}
                navbar
              >
                <MDBNavbarNav left>
                  <MDBNavItem active>
                    <MDBNavLink to='#!'>Home</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to='#!'>Link</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to='#!'>Profile</MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                </MDBNavbarNav>
              </MDBCollapse>
            </MDBContainer>
          </MDBNavbar>
        </MDBContainer>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Test from './components/Mobile_Menu/Mobile_Navbar';

function App(props) {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Test />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see any hook calls in your posted code. Although an obvious problem is that you're using class components instead of function components.

Comment: Interesting, I just copied the code from the site

Comment: Could be a problem with the library itself, or mismatched versions in the transitive dependency graph. Not something we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some kind of problem when we use the mdbootstrap Library MDBNavLink component. I didn't go deep on that to be able to explain why, though.

I solved this problem by importing the Link component from react-router-dom and use it instead with the className='nav-link'.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

//Snippet
// [....]

<MDBNavItem>
  <Link
    className='nav-link'
    exact
    to='/'
    onClick={closeCollapse('mainNavbarCollapse')}
    >
    Home
  </Link>
</MDBNavItem>

// [...]
```