# React JS Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I have this code:

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import {
        MDBNavbar, MDBNavbarBrand, MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink, MDBNavbarToggler, MDBCollapse, MDBFormInline
        } from "mdbreact";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
    import logo from '../static/logo.svg';
    import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
    import PersonAddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PersonAdd';
    import VpnKeyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VpnKey';
    import ListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/List';
    import '../App.css';
    
    function Header() {
        
        const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);
        
        const toggleCollapse = () => {
          setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        }
        
        return ( 
            <Router>
            <MDBNavbar color="indigo" dark expand="md">
              <MDBNavbarBrand>
                <strong className="white-text"> <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> </strong>
              </MDBNavbarBrand>
              <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={toggleCollapse} />
              <MDBCollapse id="navbarCollapse3" isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
                <MDBNavbarNav left>
                  <MDBNavItem active>
                    <MDBNavLink to="/crearusuario"> <PersonAddIcon /> Agregar </MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="cambiarcontrasena"> <VpnKeyIcon /> Cambiar Contraseña </MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBNavLink to="/usuarios"> <ListIcon /> Usuarios </MDBNavLink>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                </MDBNavbarNav>
                <MDBNavbarNav right>
                  <MDBNavItem>
                    <MDBFormInline waves>
                      <div className="md-form my-0"> 
                          <PersonIcon />
                          <p className="mb-auto pl-2 font-weight-bold" > Administrador </p>
                      </div>
                    </MDBFormInline>
                  </MDBNavItem>
                </MDBNavbarNav>
              </MDBCollapse>
            </MDBNavbar> 
            </Router>
          );
    }

export default Header;
```

but I'm having this error:
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have been checked it along time, but I can't find some error, what I'm doing wrong??

Here in codesandbox  [Proyect](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cori-p0jj6)

Comment: Maybe you need to import `React`, `import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Comment: ~~Is there a stack trace associated with the error that shows where in your source code this is emanating from?  At a glance I don't see anything specifically problematic in the code shown.  How certain are you that the error is coming from inside this file?~~ **Update-- scratch that, I think @Medi is probably on to something**

Comment: I think your problem is within another component.

Comment: replace function Header() { ... with const Header = ({}) => { ... Does it help?

Comment: @Medi I did and the error is yet.....@Michael Rovinsky I changed but nothing happend, the error is yet

Comment: @DeepMind could you please create codesandbox example?

Comment: Hey!!! I changed all code inside return to this: return( <p> Hello </p> ) and it's work!! the error is inside of <Router>  ................  </Router>

Comment: hi @Medi let me try

Comment: codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cori-p0jj6

Comment: I commented on some references.

Comment: Please check the solution on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67868937/255160

Answer (score 0):

Copied the solution from: [React - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384803/react-error-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of/67868937#67868937)

It seems there is some kind of problem when we use the mdbootstrap Library MDBNavLink component. I didn't go deep on that to be able to explain why, though.

I solved this problem by importing the Link component from react-router-dom and use it instead with the className='nav-link'.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

//Snippet
// [....]

<MDBNavItem>
  <Link
    className='nav-link'
    exact
    to='/'
    onClick={closeCollapse('mainNavbarCollapse')}
    >
    Home
  </Link>
</MDBNavItem>

// [...]
```